# Factorization of a real polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring, wolfram-alpha

Can I factor univariate polynomials with real coefficients as a product of quadratic trinomials and binomials corresponding to the complex conjugate and real roots using Wolfram Alpha ?

E.g.,

$$x^3-2x^2+x-2=(x^2+1)(x-2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want a factorization over the reals. One way to do this is to use decimals for your coefficients. For example, for your question you can use

> Factor[x^3 - 3.0* x^2 - 2.0]

which WA will return

> (1 x - 2) (1 x^2 + 1)

For the other example you tried, $x^4 - 2 x^2 + x - 2$, the command

> Factor[x^4-2.0*x^2+x-2.0]

will return

> (x - 1.49257) (x + 1.78537) (x^2 - 0.292798 x + 0.750527)

This will work well if there are only rational roots, but for irrational roots you might need to do extra work to get enough precision.

Comment: We are getting very close. This returns numerical coefficients, but still not always works for closed-form expression coefficients.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you mean things like factoring $(2y^2+1)x^3 - (y-5)x + y^3$? Or the factors should closed expressions like $(x - \sqrt 5)(x + \sqrt 5)$, when applicable?

Comment: The second interpretation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The problem is not all roots have closed expressions by radicals, if the polynomial is of degree $\geq 5$. For smaller degrees, one other option is to try something like
>Reduce[x^3-7 == 0, Reals]
which would give you the linear roots. In closed form when it can find one.  

So an initial factor
>Factor[-7 - 14 x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^5 ]
Gives you the irreducible parts over $\mathbb Q$ and you can try Reduce[] on each component. Not sure how to do everything as one command though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [you can do it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20x%5E3-2x%5E2%2Bx-2), using keyword "factor".

For example, Wolfram Alpha Pro returns for $factor x^4-2x^2+x-2:$

[image: x^4-2x^2+x-2]

Comment: No http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E4-2x%5E2%2Bx-2

Comment: @YvesDaoust Perhaps there is a feature of licensing policy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Was choozen the same (and later) answer. Why I'm downvoted?

Comment: I don't know who did, but you didn't understand the question it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the LHS into Wolfram Alpha gets you the form you want, about half way down the page under "Alternate forms". If that isn't what you want then I don't understand the question.

Comment: Mh, this does not always work: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-2x%5E2%2Bx-2

Comment: @YvesDaoust That one doesn't factor very nicely: [factor x^4-2x^2+x-2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E4-2x%5E2%2Bx-2)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: this is precisely what I don't want.

Comment: So what answer do you want for $x^4-2x^2+x-2$?

Comment: @user73985: the product of one trinomial and two binomials, as you can infer from the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust As I wrote, it doesn't factor nicely. Wolfram gives (x - 1.49257) (x + 1.78537) (x - (0.146399 + 0.85387 i)) (x - (0.146399 - 0.85387 i)). If you want you can then just multiply out last two factors to get [x^2 - 0.292798 x + 0.750527](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x+-+(0.146399+%2B+0.85387+i))+(x+-+(0.146399+-+0.85387+i))). The exact forms of those real numbers are horrendous.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: WA can deliver both approximate and closed-forms of the roots, both can do. "you can then just multiply out last two factors" is precisely what I want WA to perform, without having to do it manually.

Comment: I think a good way of describing what you want would be "the factorisation  over $\mathbb R$", but if Wolfram Alpha has the functionality to do that I can't find it

Comment: @user73985: generally speaking, I find it hard to obtain answers limited to the real domain.